# Wordpress data attribute security right value

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, security

I have client side an html form who send with ajax to my server the data. The problem is anybody can change the input value (right click and "inspect the element" with chrome) and the data get server side can be wrong.

Example:
1. My HTML form 
2. I send data to my server with ajax
3. With PHP i get data from client side

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
<input id="send" type="submit" value="send">
</form>


$('#send').on('click', function(){
  var user_id = jQuery('input[name="user_id"]').val();  
  jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
          data:{
          'action':'my_form',
          'user_id': user_id,
          },
           success:function(data){
            console.log(data); 
           }
   });
});

function my_form(){
    $user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
}
```

Anybody can change the hidden "user_id" field and set the value to 123 or 4856 for example. The data get in $user_id server side can be wrong.
So what can i do to be sure that the data from client side is right ?

p.s: sorry for my english

Comment: Is this logged in user id?

Comment: Yes its the user who is log

Answer (score 0):

If it is logged in user id then don't trust on client side values instead use following in your php code

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$userid = $current_user->ID;
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user